# Is there anyway to set the counties' border line colors in county_choropleth? Or any other alternative way?

Tags: r, choroplethr

My data includes FIPS code, County Name, and Population size. Using the choroplethr package, my current code is

```
county_choropleth(Countydata,  legend = "Population",county_zoom =TennCounties)
```

Is there anyway to set the counties' border line colors in county_choropleth?
Or any other alternative way?

Comment: Here's a blog post that might be helpful: https://arilamstein.com/blog/2015/07/02/exploring-the-demographics-of-ferguson-missouri/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this question is still needed answered but I overlayed the county borders to my choropleth map by saving the choropleth to a DF then adding my county map.

I used:

```
name_of_choropleth_df + geom_polygon(data=df_counties, 
                                     aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
                                     alpha=0, color="black", size=0.2)
```

My df_counties came from the US Census Bureau website and I modified it to only include specific counties. Alpha, color, and size can be whatever you want.